# Design Advice for Posting Messages to a Server

Tags: android

I am designing an application that needs to update a server at regular intervals, but I am unsure of how to go about sending these updates.

This is what I am trying to do:
When my Activity starts, I must send an initial connection message to the server.  After the connection has been established, I will send one new message to the server every second.  When the user performs some action that the server needs to know about, that message will be added to a queue.  Every second or so, my app would then check the queue for messages to send.  If one is available, it is sent.  If the queue is empty, a simple Keep Alive message should be sent to maintain the connection.

My question is, what would be the best strategy for me to implement this?  Should I be using a separate Thread?  Or a Service?  Or AsyncTasks?

> My thoughts so far: The connection does not need to be maintained past
>   the lifecycle of the activity, so it seems to me that a Service would
>   be overkill.

And how should I handle scheduling the updates?  Should I be using a MessageQueue with a Looper?  Or a ScheduledExecutorService?  Or a Handler?

> My thoughts so far:
>       My understanding is that MessageQueue blocks until it receives a
>   message to send.
>       I'm not sure this is what I want.  My plan was just to send Keep
>   Alive messages
>       when the queue is empty, not block until a new message arrives.

I'm totally new to this sort of stuff so I might be going about this entirely the wrong way. I'd be happy to hear any advice you can offer.

Comment: Every second seems a bit much, if you have 20000 users, that would be 20000 hits per second.

Comment: That would certainly be a problem for most applications, but I don't think it is in my case.  The server is on a robot, and no more than a few users will ever connect to it at one time.  In addition, the connection is terminated if a message is not received in more than a couple of seconds, so I am forced to send messages that frequently.

Comment: And then use the ADK?  That would be cool if Android devices were the only method of interacting with the robot.  However, the system needs to support (and has already been implemented on) iOS, as well as other platforms.

Comment: @theisenp: I'm not sure if it is of use but have you looked at `IntentService`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: @MisterSquonk I have not looked at IntentServices yet, I'll take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: What about [one of these](http://store.weburban.com/la-robotics-club-kit.html)

Comment: @Merlin That looks pretty awesome, but unfortunately I have to treat this as a software problem.  It's not up to me to decide the hardware on the on the bot.  I just have to figure out the best way to send UDP packets to a server at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a separate thread with a sleep statement (or android equivalent) ... keeping it as simple as possible is necessary with your intended timings and the fact that the app is not intended for unattended execution

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.  Off the top of my head it sounds like that should fit my needs.  I'll test it out and report back, thanks Merlin.

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well for me, thanks for the simple solution Merlin!

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. Keep in mind the user: make sure this does not generate too much traffic. You should cancel the communication when app is not active.
2. When phone goes to sleep, there is no network communication.
3. You should not send/receive data on UI thread. All that you said are ok: background thread, service and AsyncTask.
4. If you have only one Activity to update then use AsyncTask, as it's the easiest. When Activity is resumed, notify the comm task to stop.
5. If you need to update different Activities, then use Service. Service should send broadcasts when some data is received and interested Activities can register to those events. This is elegant as only active (in foreground) Activities receive broadcasts.